# Quantum gravity in affine picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, tensor-calculus

I am studying an article which is about quantum gravity (M. Martellini, "Quantum Gravity in the Eddington Purely Affine Picture," [Phys. Rev. D **29** (1984) 2746](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.29.2746)). I have come to eq. 2.11a which is

\begin{equation}
\overline{\nabla}_{\rho}\overline{K}_{\alpha\beta}=0
\end{equation}

where, $K_{\mu\nu}$ is Ricci tensor

\begin{align}
&\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu}=\overline{\Gamma}^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu}+\sqrt{\lambda}\gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu} \\
&\overline{\Gamma}^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu}=\overline{\Gamma}^{\alpha}_{(\mu\nu)},\ \gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu}=\gamma^{\alpha}_{(\mu\nu)}, \\
&\overline{\nabla}_{\rho}(\overline{\Gamma})\overline{K}(\overline{\Gamma})=0.
\end{align}

Somehow, from the above equation of motion we should derive the eq. 2.11b which is

\begin{align}
&[\overrightarrow{\overline{\nabla}}_{\rho}\overrightarrow{\overline{\partial}}_{\kappa}\mathfrak{I}^{\kappa\mu\nu}_{\lambda\alpha\beta}-2\overline{K}_{\lambda(\alpha}\delta^{\mu\nu}_{\beta)\rho}+(\overline{\nabla}_{\rho}\overline{\Gamma}^{\sigma}_{\kappa\lambda})\mathfrak{I}^{\kappa\mu\nu}_{\sigma\alpha\beta}+(\overline{\nabla}_{\rho}\overline{\Gamma}^{(\mu}_{\tau\eta})\mathfrak{I}^{\nu)\tau\eta}_{\lambda\alpha\beta}+\overline{\Gamma}^{\sigma}_{\kappa\lambda}\overline{\nabla}_{\rho}\mathfrak{I}^{\kappa\mu\nu}_{\sigma\alpha\beta}+\overline{\Gamma}^{(\mu}_{\tau\eta}\overline{\nabla}_{\rho}\mathfrak{I}^{\nu)\eta\tau}_{\lambda\alpha\beta}]\gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu} \\
&=-2\sqrt{\lambda}\gamma^{\lambda}_{\kappa\sigma}(\overline{\nabla}_{\rho}\mathfrak{I}^{\kappa\mu\nu}_{\lambda\alpha\beta})\gamma^{\sigma}_{\mu\nu}+2\sqrt{\lambda}\gamma^{\delta}_{\rho\tau}[\delta^{\eta\tau}_{\alpha\beta}(\partial_{\kappa}\mathfrak{I}^{\kappa\mu\nu}_{\lambda\delta\eta}+\overline{\Gamma}^{\sigma}_{\kappa\lambda}\mathfrak{I}^{\kappa\mu\nu}_{\sigma\delta\eta}+\overline{\Gamma}^{(\mu}_{\kappa\sigma}\mathfrak{I}^{\nu)\kappa\sigma}_{\lambda\delta\eta})]\gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}+2\lambda\gamma^{\delta}_{\rho\tau}(\mathfrak{I}^{\kappa\mu\nu}_{\lambda\delta\eta}\delta^{\eta\tau}_{\alpha\beta})\gamma^{\lambda}_{\kappa\sigma}\gamma^{\sigma}_{\mu\nu}
\end{align}

where
\begin{align}
&\mathfrak{I}^{\kappa\mu\nu}_{\lambda\eta\delta} \equiv (\delta^{\mu}_{\lambda}\delta^{\nu\kappa}_{\eta\delta}-\delta^{\kappa}_{\lambda}\delta^{\mu\nu}_{\eta\delta}) \\
&\delta^{\nu\kappa}_{\eta\delta}\equiv\frac{1}{2}(\delta^{\nu}_{\eta}\delta^{\kappa}_{\delta}+\delta^{\nu}_{\delta}\delta^{\kappa}_{\eta})
\end{align}

I have tried it in both ways:

1. Begining from covariant derivative of Ricci Tensor to find above eq.
2. Begining from the result to find covariant derivative of Ricci Tensor.

I could not find it in both ways. Can anyone help me? Besides, why are we using the equation of motion in this form?

Note: since we are in purely affine picture, we are not allowed to use the metric tensor.